# how much max RAM will be supported by intel Core i7-860 Processor (8M Cache, 2.80 GHz)

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have the requirement of about 32 GB RAM.
I i use  `intel Core i7-860 Processor (8M Cache, 2.80 GHz)`

WIll that be OK with

```
intel S5520SC Server Motherboard
```

Comment: I would personnaly recommend a XEON with that much RAM, and that kind of Motherboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motherboard is only compatible with Xeon 55xx series CPUs and not the Core i7.

It states that it has 12 sockets, however I am unable to find further details. I used 4GB sticks in the previous version of this board without problems, however I cannot find any specification pages that back this up.

...Edit - Found [this link](http://serverconfigurator.intel.com/configure-memory.aspx?id=MTY2NCMxLDI1MTcjMSwyNjE4IzIsMjUzMyMx&ShowNavigation=false), it shows compatibility for up to 8GB modules, this is not for your motherboard, but it is for one with the same chipset - which is usually the limiting factor in things like this.

Comment: Actually i have not bought that yet but my main consideration is 32Gb RAM.Can you please advice which board and processor i should buy.
My budget is around 1200$ both for processor and Motherboard

Comment: Is that just for the CPU and board, or does it also include the memory, case, psu etc.?... If you look up the price of some proper server cases you may get a shock!

Comment: That was just cpuu and board. Without RAM  roughly how much will the computer be ready. under $2000 is possible?

Comment: I would say it is possible - but you may not want to. Anything that can use 32GB is likely to use quite a bit of horse power and if you cut costs, you may regret it... Like buying an expensive sports car but then having an acceleration limiter put on... I would seriously go for either quad core or dual-quad cores... You may be able to get for under $2000, but it will be a stretch. What country are you in? I will try and look something up for you.

Comment: I live in Australia. Thats not production server and i just using in my home fro trying all sort of LAN , WAN , Office server replication thing. I need to have many Virtual machines so thats why i need 32GB RAM

Comment: I don't know any shops in Australia, but I doubt you will be able to get a complete system like this for $2000 - That quantity of memory alone, using 4GB sticks will probably cost around $2000 on its own... I really don't know what to recommend here... Whenenver I have sold a system of this sort of specification, usually, the client doesn't have a budget... Sorry I can't really be much more help.... What are you using this system for?

Comment: Using a hypervisor such as ESXi allows very good memory management - honestly, if you do anything that takes up 32GBs, you are going to want at least 2x dual or quad core CPUs, and this is going to go way over your budget. I recommend that you take a look at getting around 8-16GB, single (or dual) quad core system as this should work well in a non production environmeny.

Comment: How much does quad core xeon cost. Will this work Intel XEON E5410 Quad Core, 2.33GHz, 12MB Cache, LGA771, 1333FSB, Passive. its around 500$

Comment: That will work, but I do not think with this board. Use this tool - http://serverconfigurator.intel.com/ - It should be able to help you. You will most likely want to look for the Xeon 3x series, or even a standard (but solid) high end desktop system. Lastly, don't forget to check Dell or HP, I am not the biggest fan of off the shelf systems, but the few times I have used them, they are usually rock solid bits of kit... (still far away from promoting their desktop systems though!)

Answer (score 2):

The Intel S5520SC Motherboard can up to hold 96 GB RAM

Each memory slot can hold **DDR3 PC3-10600** or **DDR3 PC3-8500** with a **maximum of 8GB per slot**.

*[Source](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=S5520SC)*

if you want to use that Core i7-860 you're limited to 24 GB RAM. If you want more get a Xeon mainbard like the one you posted.